# Do I need Transit visa for Germany, travelling from India to Poland via Germany with Polish D-Type National Visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, germany, indian-citizens, poland

I am going to Poland (Delhi-Frankfurt-Warsaw) with Polish National Visa.
Do I need Transit visa for layover in Frankfurt?

Comment: When you say "Polish National Visa", do you mean something that is not a uniform short-stay Schengen visa, but a residence permit specifically for Poland? Usually even the later ought to be valid for transit through other Schengen countries on the way to the destination, but the particular kind of visa/permit you have might come with special rules. Please edit your question to contain the _exact_ title of the document you have.

Comment: Yes, it's D- Type National visa on which I can stay in Schengen area for short time.

Comment: Well since Germany is in the Schengen area, there should be no problem then.

Comment: @pnuts: However, the official terminology for a type D visa (see regulation 264/2010 as linked in my answer) is "_long_ stay visa". In its capacity of a long-stay visa it gives the holder rights in other states _comparable_ to that of a uniform short-stay visa.

Answer (score 5):

Since April 2010, holders of national D-type visas of a Schengen country can travel freely in the Schengen area, as long as they observe the 90/180 day rule for the time they spend on *other* Schengen countries than the one their visa is for.

(See [regulation (EU) 265/2010](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:32010R0265) amending the Schengen Convention; further amended by [610/2013](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=celex:32013R0610) to clarify the 90/180 day rule).

This means that your Polish D-visa will allow you to enter the Schengen area at Frankfurt and proceed within Schengen to Poland. You don't need an additional visa for that.

Comment: @SamirHalder Don't forget to mark this answer as accepted if you feel it fully answers your question. You can do this by clicking on the check mark by the voting arrows.